# Is there a way to fix maximum recursion level in python 3?

Tags: python, json, recursion, bokeh

I'm trying to build a state map for data across a decade, with a slider to select the year displayed on the map. The sort of display where a user can pick 2014 and the map will show the data for 2014.

I merged the data I want to show with the appropriate shapefile. I end up with 733 rows and 5 columns - as many as 9 rows per county with the same county name and coordinates.

Everything seems to be okay until I try to build the map. This error message is returned:

> OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached

I've tried resetting the recursion limit using `sys.setrecursionlimit` but can't get past that error.

I haven't been able to find an answer on SO that I understand, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm using bokeh and json to build the map. I've tried using `sys.setrecursionlimit` but I get the same error message no matter how high I go.

I used the same code last week but couldn't get data from different years to display because I was using a subset of the data. Now that I've fixed that, I'm stuck on this error message.

```py
def json_data(selectedYear):
    yr = selectedYear
    murders = murder[murder['Year'] == yr]
    merged = mergedfinal
    merged.fillna('0', inplace = True)
    merged_json = json.loads(merged.to_json())
    json_data = json.dumps(merged_json)
    return json_data

geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data(2018))

palette=brewer['YlOrRd'][9]
palette = palette[::-1]

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 60, nan_color = '#d9d9d9')

hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [ ('County/City','@NAME'),('Victims', '@Victims')])

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8,width = 500, height = 30,
                     border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), 
                     orientation = 'horizontal')

p = figure(title = 'Firearm Murders in Virginia', plot_height = 600 , plot_width = 950, toolbar_location = None, tools = [hover])
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.visible=False
p.yaxis.visible=False

p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,fill_color = {'field' :'Victims', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)


p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    year = Slider.value
    new_data = json_data(year)
    geosource.geojson = new_data
    p.title.text = 'Firearm Murders in VA'


slider = Slider(title = 'Year', start = 2009, end = 2018, step = 1, value = 2018)
slider.on_change('value', update_plot)

layout = column(p,widgetbox(slider))
curdoc().add_root(layout)

output_notebook()

show(layout)
```

The same code worked well enough when I was using a more limited dataset. Here is the full context of the error message:

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-efd821491ac3> in <module>()
      8     return json_data
      9 
---> 10 geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data(2018))
     11 
     12 palette=brewer['YlOrRd'][9]

<ipython-input-50-efd821491ac3> in json_data(selectedYear)
      4     merged = mergedfinal
      5     merged.fillna('0', inplace = True)
----> 6     merged_json = json.loads(merged.to_json())
      7     json_data = json.dumps(merged_json)
      8     return json_data

/Users/mcuddy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_json(self, path_or_buf, orient, date_format, double_precision, force_ascii, date_unit, default_handler, lines)
   1087                             force_ascii=force_ascii, date_unit=date_unit,
   1088                             default_handler=default_handler,
-> 1089                             lines=lines)
   1090 
   1091     def to_hdf(self, path_or_buf, key, **kwargs):

/Users/mcuddy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in to_json(path_or_buf, obj, orient, date_format, double_precision, force_ascii, date_unit, default_handler, lines)
     37             obj, orient=orient, date_format=date_format,
     38             double_precision=double_precision, ensure_ascii=force_ascii,
---> 39             date_unit=date_unit, default_handler=default_handler).write()
     40     else:
     41         raise NotImplementedError("'obj' should be a Series or a DataFrame")

/Users/mcuddy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in write(self)
     83             date_unit=self.date_unit,
     84             iso_dates=self.date_format == 'iso',
---> 85             default_handler=self.default_handler)
     86 
     87 

OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached
```

Comment: So where is it recursing?

Comment: Usually if you hit the recursion limit it is because you have infinite recursion somewhere (not because you just didn't have enough stack). Otherwise if you still run out of stack than you should probably do an iterative solution.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger line by line and see what line it starts failing on.

Comment: Don't see the recursion??

Comment: Not related to the recursion problem: Don't use variables with the same name as the function, like `json_data`.

Comment: Also don't you think redefining your function name "json_data" in the json_data function is problematic?

Comment: `json_data` is a local variable inside the function only, it does not redefine the function or affect anything outside the function. As others have mentioned, the most imorptant thing here is more context from the error message (i.e. line number the line of code that actually raised the exception, or even the full stracktrace)

Comment: Also @MC76, FYI `on_change` with real python callbacks only works with Bokeh server applications, which this is not. Bokeh apps can be embedded in notebooks but they are structured differently.

Comment: @bigreddot It is obvious that he is not redefining the higher scoped function. I am trying to draw attention to the fact that no recursion is happening, as the OP indicates. It possible that the author thinks he is somehow calling the function, when in fact he has defined it again at the local scope, which effectively redefines it, since Python will find it at the local scope instead of the higher scope.

Comment: `OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached` is a pretty clear indication that recursion is, in fact, happening, somewhere. The only question is where, which would be answered by the OP providing more context from the error message.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I posted the full message in the original question, and am going to dig into Bohek apps in notebooks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem!

I narrowed my problem down to the `.to_json` step. For some reason when I merged my geopandas file on the right:

```
Neighbourhoods_merged = df_2016.merge(gdf_neighbourhoods, how = "left", on = "Neighbourhood#")
```

I ran into the recursion error. I found success by switching the two:

```
Neighbourhoods_merged = gdf_neighbourhoods.merge(df_2016, how = "left", on = "Neighbourhood#")
```

This is what worked for me. Infuriatingly I have no idea why this works, but I hope this might help someone else with the same error!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by changing the merge direction.

so, If you want to merge two dataframes A and B, and A has type of 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame' and B has 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
', you should merge them with pd.merge(A,B,on="some column'), not with the opposite direction.

I think the maximum recursion error comes when you execute .to_json() method to the pandas dataframe type with POLYGON type in it.

When you change the direction of merge and change the type to GeoDataFrame, .to_json() is executed without problem even they have POLYGON type column in it.

I spent 2 hours with this, and I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a higher recursion depth, you can set it using sys:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

That being said, your error is most likely the result of an infinite recursion, which may be the case if increasing the depth doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue when trying to display a pandas pivot table a with shiny.  I believe the problem is that the column data types were not string.  My problem was solved by converting column names to strings:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```